# How to display a category on the site?

Tags: craft3, categories

Please help me to display the categories. I have a category group with a huge category tree. Can I somehow output not the whole group of categories, but only a certain category with its child categories?
My tree looks like this:

```
+ category 1 (cat_id=111)
++ subcategory 1-1
++ subcategory 1-2
++ subcategory 1-3
+ category 2 (cat_id=222)
++ subcategory 2-1
++ subcategory 2-2
++ subcategory 2-3
```

I want to get from my group only this:

```
+ category 2
++ subcategory 2-1
++ subcategory 2-2
++ subcategory 2-3
```

I try to do this to use this construction:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories().ancestorOf(222).ancestorDist(3).all() %}
```

I understand that this construction should take a category with ID 222 and output it and its descendants

But this don't work. What i do wrong? ((

Answer (score 2):

This is solution:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories().descendantOf(222).descendantDist(3).all() %}
```